# How to used event handlers, double click and keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events

Where it says "double click here" I am trying to get it to function correctly. When clicked it should then say "Hello! You pressed the right button. Now you get my secret message. Press a key on the keyboard!". Then used the `kepress` to create another message. Both of my even handlers don't seem to be functional.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    function updateDocument(){
        $("#Document").html("Hello! You pressed the right button. Now you get my secret message. Press a key on the keyboard!");
        $("#Document").html("\n");
        $("#Document").html("\n");
    };      
    document.getElementById("here").addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
        updateDocument();
    });
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(val){
        var x = val.keyCode;
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(x);        
        $("#Document").append(letter);
    })
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="triggered.js"></script>
<div id="trigger1" class="trigger"> 
    double click 
    <p id = "here"> Here! </p>
    <br>
    <p id ="Document"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please mention what issue you are facing here.

Answer (score 0):

your second and third `.html(...)` are replacing your previous text.
So it was technically working.

Here it is working correctly.

```js
 window.onload = function(){


        function updateDocument(){

            $("#Document").html("Hello! You pressed the right button. Now you get my secret message. Press a key on the keyboard!\n\n");

        };


        $("#here").on("dblclick", function(){
            updateDocument();
        });

        $(document).on("keypress", function(val){
            var x = val.keyCode;
            var letter = String.fromCharCode(x);        
            $("#Document").append(letter);
        })

    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id = "trigger1" class = "trigger"> double click 
        <p id = "here"> Here! </p>

        <br>
        <p id ="Document"></p>
    </div>
```